# How would I connect to a proxy on Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-studio

So I am running Ubuntu Studio on my laptop and what do I do to connect to a proxy? I search for proxy and in network settings their is no PROXY tab. What are key words in the tabs to look for?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script in response to a [question at Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152260/70524) about setting proxies:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
HTTP_PROXY_HOST="proxy.example.com"
HTTP_PROXY_PORT=3128
HTTPS_PROXY_HOST="proxy.example.com"
HTTPS_PROXY_PORT=3128

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode manual
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host "$HTTP_PROXY_HOST"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port "$HTTP_PROXY_PORT"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host "$HTTPS_PROXY_HOST"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https port "$HTTPS_PROXY_PORT"

sudo sed -i.bak '/http[s]::proxy/Id' /etc/apt/apt.conf
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf <<EOF
Acquire::http::proxy "http://$HTTP_PROXY_HOST:$HTTP_PROXY_PORT/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://$HTTPS_PROXY_HOST:$HTTPS_PROXY_PORT/";
EOF

sudo sed -i.bak '/http[s]_proxy/Id' /etc/environment
sudo tee -a /etc/environment <<EOF
http_proxy="http://$HTTP_PROXY_HOST:$HTTP_PROXY_PORT/"
https_proxy="http://$HTTPS_PROXY_HOST:$HTTPS_PROXY_PORT/"
EOF
```

Save to a file (call it `proxy.sh`), edit it using your favourite editor to set the values of the `*_PROXY_*` variables and run:

```
chmod +x proxy.sh
./proxy.sh
```

It does, as far as I am aware, exactly what the GUI does (if based on a GNOME environment, which Ubuntu Studio is).

Answer (score 1):

You can set your proxy via the terminal.

You should, for that, edit the following files:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/environment
/etc/apt/apt.conf
/usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

These files must have the following contents:

```
    sudo -i
    nano  /etc/bash.bashrc
  ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Control + O, save file.

```
    sudo -i
    nano  /etc/environment
   ----------------------------------------------------------
    http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
    ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
   ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Control + O, save file.

```
    sudo -i
    nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
    Acquire::https::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
    Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Control + O, save file.

```
    sudo -i
    nano  /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf 
    -------------------------------- 
    HTTPProxyServer proxyserver.net
    HTTPProxyPort port
    HTTPProxyUsername username
    HTTPProxyPassword password
    --------------------------------
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano