# Where is proxy information stored in ubuntu

Tags: proxy

I saved one URL as proxy during install time. At which place is the proxy URL stored in system.

One place is apt conf folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Places used in https://askubuntu.com/a/526900/158442, as well

Comment: This [Link](https://askubuntu.com/a/151047/710635) may help you.